# XCode 5.1.1 iOS simulator no longer lets you simulate weak/disconnected network conditions

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Previously before XCode 5.1.1, disconnecting the Mac running the simulator from the network OR using the Network Link Conditioner was enough to replicate poor or disconnected network connections on the iOS simulator.

After the XCode 5.1.1 update, the simulator does not appear to respond to network changes and there does not seem to be anyway to make it change its default network status.
I've submitted a bug to Apple about this but I was curious if anyone else has found a work around for this issue.

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and Mountain Lion with the July 2012 edition of the Hardware IO Tools for XCode installed. The latest version of the Hardware IO Tools appears to not install correctly on Mountain Lion so I'm on the previous version.

Comment: I just tested the Network Link Conditioner (in my Mac OS "System Preferences", which I downloaded by going to Xcode's "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer Tools" and choosing "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode") and the Xcode 5.1.1 simulator correctly reflected the degraded network performance corresponding to the "Profile" I selected in the Network Link Conditioner. Bottom line, I cannot reproduce the behavior you report. Can you share more information about how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'm using Mountain Lion and the Nov 2012 version of the Hardware IO Tools (work hasn't approved a Mavericks upgrade yet) and this did happen on the rest of our work pcs. The OS versions might be a factor here.. I'll see if my Mavericks Setup at home has the same issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Network Link Conditioner tool in the Hardware IO Tools package does not affect localhost traffic.